# Float with different text sizes is breaking

Tags: html, css, css-float, overlap

Basically I have several `li` with different text sizes that don't need have the same height. But I'd like it behave like a row and not like the image below:

[image: screenshot]

I appreciate solutions that did not use `table`, `flexbox` or `inline-block`.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
body { margin: 50px; }

.box {
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.box ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

.box li {
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-right: 5%;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 30%;
}

.box li:nth-child(3n) { margin-right: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <ul>
    <li>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis.</li>
    <li>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá, depois divoltis porris, paradis.</li>
    <li>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis.</li>
    <li>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá, depois divoltis porris, paradis.</li>
    <li>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis.</li>
    <li>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis.</li>
    <li>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá, depois divoltis porris, paradis.</li>
    <li>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis.</li>
    <li>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis.</li>
    <li>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis.</li>
    <li>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá, depois divoltis porris, paradis.</li>
    <li>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis.</li>
    <li>Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá, depois divoltis porris, paradis.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you define "like a row"? Do you mean three items max in every row? Or maybe each item a row?

Answer (score 0):

This issue purely because the css applied to the third list item and the third item is not always in the third column.

```
.box li:nth-child(3n) { margin-right: 0; }
```

This basically does not guarantee the third item to be in the third column. So to resolve this, just remove the style above and set the margin-right on .box li to have smaller percentage value or absolute value such as 15px as I did below.

See this on JSFiddle [click](https://jsfiddle.net/hs6rxvxr/)

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
body { margin: 50px; }

.box {
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.box ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

.box li {
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 30%;
}
```

I have added numbers in front of the list item text so you can see which item is which. As you can see the css code snippet, I have changed the margin-right to 15px and removed the .box style. Hope this helps.

Comment: In this way I'll never have the same margins sizes, doesn't work for me. But thank you. :)

Comment: Also, I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve. If you look at the updated JSFiddle link, you can see the margins are all same and aligned quite nicely. Also the css class ".box li:nth-child(3n) { margin-right: 0; }" is not quite correct as the list <li> isn't going to always line up with every 3x elements. Have a look at the numbers I put in the JSFiddle. (3n isn't going to be applied to 4th element but the 4th element is in third column).

Comment: I wish I could explain clearer, but without what your goal is, please understand that it is not very easy to do so. Let me know if you have questions regarding this.